# Token ring topology and token passing concepts

Tags: lan, layer2

In token ring topology, if a host needs to send data, it grabs the token and sends data. Once it receives it again it frees the token.
This is what I know about token ring
Is token is held by host, while data transmits through the ring or data frame is appended to the token and passed?
some websites explain as host holds the token and data passes as frame and once data received by sender , sender frees the token if it completes, but some websites and my lecturer explain that data frame is appended with the token and passed.

How the ring topology works with token?
How token looks like?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It starts out with an empty token being circulated. The empty token has a priority, and a station must have an equal or higher priority to use the empty token. A host wanting to send something seizes the empty token. Then it sends a frame, and the frame header has an Access Control field with a token in it. The receiving host will change the token back to `0`. When the frame circles all the way around to the host sending the frame, the sender will see that the token is `0`, and it will remove the frame data and send the empty token back around.

The token is part of the frame. It can be seen conceptually that the host holds the token, but the token is really part of the frame header for a data frame.